# Search for the Library/Header file where a method is declared

Tags: c++, libraries

I have to use the libraries provided by a camera manufacturer in my project. I am using **Visual Studio 2015**. I have incorporated all the header files suggested by VS 2015 after writing `#include`.

I have specified the path of include files and libraries in VS 2015 and it is able to find most of the methods.

**Problem:** When I compile my code, I get a following linker error :

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned int __cdecl
>   LvModule::GetInt32(unsigned int,int *)" (?GetInt32@LvModule@@QEAAIIPEAH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CCamera::CloseCamera(void)" (?CloseCamera@CCamera@@QEAAXXZ) ImageProcessingSidd C:Path\ImageProcessing.obj  1

**Question:** How can I search in my system the header file/Library where the method `GetInt32()` has been defined. I have seen somebody before searching for header file by using some command like `kgrab` (not sure about the exact command)

Comment: The frontend parser probably knows where the declaration is. Go to the site where it is used (the linker error tells you that), select it, and press F12. You won't be able to find the *definition*, of course, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not a matter of function declaration in an header file. It's a linking problem. Did you forgot to link librairies to your project ?

Comment: Is this a product from Leutron Vision called Simplon?  Stop using it asap, they went out of business 3 years ago.

Comment: I have linked the libraries whichever I knew and it is able to find most of the methods. But offcourse there are more libraries which need to be linked but I don't know which one....So, I want to know, is there any method with which I can know the missing libary which need to be specified.

Comment: @HansPassant: No, it is from NET camera manufacturer.

Comment: Do you know what [product, library, framework ...] `LvModule::GetInt32` and `CCamera::CloseCamera` belong to? It could help to find the exact lib or dll file that contains them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my advice would be *RTFM*!

More seriously, MSDN documentation always gives the header and library where an API function lies, and so do all decent libraries.

I can see in the posted error `LvModule` and `CCamera` references. I assume they come from a library and that you know what library they come from. You should then identify to what *product* those references belong, and look where and how it is installed on your machine, and how the functions are documented.

Of course, you can also search for every lib and dll file on your disk and use `dumpbin` to identify what symbols they declare, but personnally I prefere first way.

Comment: I have already included the path of the library to he best of my knowledge and I shouldn't get this linker error. I am getting this error means that still some library is missing. Which library is missing and where is it present, that I don't know and therefore, I want to know some echnique by which  I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

To search Libraries, you'll first want to open a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" (look in the Start Menu near where Visual Studio is installed)

As an initial demonstration, run the command on just one library to see what comes out:

```
dumpbin mfc120.lib /exports
```

*(must be run from the directory that actually holds that library)*

Then run the program `dumpbin` like this:

```
dumpbin *.lib /exports | findstr "LvModule::GetInt32"
```

Run the command in any directory where the missing library *might* be found.

That will search through all exported functions in the libraries in the current directory and find any reference to `LvModule::GetInt32`.

You'll have to continue your research from there to find out if it is exactly the missing function you need, but its a good starting point.

---

**TL;DR:** dumpbin is good for looking in libraries.

---

Why do I have to write your scripts for you?
Do you even program?

**Program: SearchFor.bat %1**

```
@echo off
@for /F "delims=;" %%a in ('dir \*.lib /B /S') do call :SearchText "%%a" %1
exit /B

:SearchText
dumpbin %1 /exports | findstr %2 > NUL
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 echo MATCH IN %1
exit /B
```

Run this as:

```
C:\>SearchFor LvModule::GetInt32
```

Comment: I tried to use your command in `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015` and `MSBuild Comand Prompt for VS 2015`. The first one didn't give any message and the latter said ``dumpbin is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: Did you run it in the directory where your library files are stored?  Do you understand what "`*.lib`" means, and that it only refers to the current directory?

Comment: If I knew the directory of the library, I would have already specified its path to VS2015. But the problem is, I don't know which library do I need to include further and that's why I need to search the library which incorporates the missing method.

Comment: That is why it's called "searching"  You have to look in many places to eventually find the right one.

Comment: isn't it possible to search it in the complete system?